# Comparing two very different text files in Python

Tags: python

I’m new to Python and would like to compare two text files.  The
first text file has the following format:

```
Date: 11/30/2010
Time: 21:04:10
From: John
To: Ed
Protocol: SMTP

Date: 11/30/2010
Time: 15:14:19
From: Fred
To: John
Protocol: SMTP

Date: 08/15/2010
Time: 09:11:12
From: Sue
To: Tom
Protocol: POP
.
.
.
```

The second file has the following format:

```
Data:3 xxxx 2010-08-15 09:11:12
Type IV send now
Sue -> Tom
Protocol: SMTP

Data:23 xxxx 2010-07-15 09:11:12
Type V send now
Fred -> ED
Protocol: FTP
          SMTP

Data:45 xxxx 2010-06-15 09:11:12
Type IV send now
Fred -> Sue
Protocol: POP
          SMTP
.
.
.
```

I need to read a block of name/value pairs from file 1 and find all blocks that match in file 2 using “Date, Time, From, To“ available in file 1.  For example, the only match in the file would be between:

```
Date: 08/15/2010
Time: 09:11:12
From: Sue
To: Tom
Protocol: POP
```

AND

```
Data:45 xxxx 2010-06-15 09:11:12
Type IV send now
Fred -> Sue
Protocol: POP
          SMTP
```

I’ve started the following code but am stuck on how best to perform this 
parsing and comparison.  Based on other languages I’ve used, I would put the five name/value pairs from line 1 into a data type that I could then reference to find matches in the second file.  Any help would be most
appreciated.  Thanks.

```
import os

def main():
    #read file
    file1 = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/file1.txt"),"r")
    lines = file1.readlines()

#parse
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    #print(line)
    if line == "Date:":
        print(line)
        file1.close()

main()
```

Comment: Look into the Regular Expression library (using `import re`). It should make the problem seem less large.

Comment: How big these files are going to be?

Comment: They could be quite large .. I've tried using numpy but it was too advanced for me at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res` is the list that is initially an empty list. As you progress through each line of file line, if the line has file, then, `convert the fate format to match date format in file2`.

Check if `date` is present in file 2. If so, get the block index, from where to where(assumed that each block is separated by a newline) and append append the content of file1 block and file2 block as a list to `res`!

iterate the found list, if there exists more than one match in file2. Depends on the contents of file2! This scenario is not handled below.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime


def main():
    #read file
    file1 = open("file1.txt","r")
    lines = file1.read().splitlines()
    file2 = open("file2.txt","r")
    cmplines = file2.read().splitlines()
    res=[]
    for ind,line in enumerate(lines):
        line = line.strip()
        if "Date:" in line:
            l,date=line.split(":")
            date=date.strip()
            date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
            date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            found = [i for i,l in enumerate(cmplines) if date in l] # check for date in file2
            if found:
                end = lines[ind:].index("") if "" in lines[ind:] else len(lines) #get the block end index for file1
                end2 = cmplines[found[0]:].index("") if "" in cmplines[found[0]:] else len(cmplines)#get the block end index for file2
                res.append([lines[ind:end],cmplines[found[0]:end2]])

    for file1_content,file2_content in res:
        print file1_content,file2_content
        print "\n"
    file1.close()
    file2.close()

main()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This really helps.  I think between this and some regex, I should be set.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this took a little bit but I got a good beta for you to toy with. I wasn't really sure how you wanted to frame the output but it is almost there.

```
import datetime
import re


file1 = open("file1.txt", mode="r", newline="\n")
file2 = open("file2.txt", mode="r", newline="\n")

fixdate = re.compile("[0-9].*?\s[a-z]\D*")

lines2 = [lines.strip() for lines in file2.readlines()[:-3]]


for i in range(len(lines2)):
    line = re.sub(fixdate, "", lines2[i])
    dict2 = dict()
    if "Protocol" in line:
        li = line.split(" ")
        li.append(lines2[i+1].lstrip().strip())
        for l in li:
            proto = re.search("(?<=Protocol:) %s" % l, str(file1.read()))
            if proto is None:
                pass
            else:
                print("Matched Protocol: %s" % l)

elif "Data" in line:
    li = re.sub("Data:", "", line)
    dt = li.split(" ")
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt[0], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    date = re.search('(?<=Date:) %s' % d, str(file1.read()))
    times = re.search('(?<=Time:) %s' % dt[1], str(file1.read()))
    if date is not None:
        print("Matched Date %s" % d)
    else:
        pass
    if times is not None:
        print("Matched Time: %s" % dt)
    else:
        pass

elif "->" in line:
    li = line.split("->")

    sender = re.search('(?<=To:) %s' % li[0], str(file1.read()))
    if sender is None:
        pass
    else:
        print("Matched Sender: %s" % li[0])
    recv = re.search('(?<=From:) %s' % li[1], str(file1.read()))
    if recv is None:
        pass
    else:
        print("Matched Receiver: %s" % li[1])
```